# Exception is truncated in scala shell

Tags: scala, exception, scala-shell

I ran some code in scala shell and get the following error. It looks like the exception is truncated, I can not get what the root cause for the NPE. How can I see the full stacktrace in scala shell ? Thanks

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 37 more
```

Comment: Try the -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth JVM option.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Might be useful if you show how you're running your Scala code.